# WPF DataGrid Выравнивание заголовка колонки

Tags: wpf

```
protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Description")
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

                DataGridTemplateColumn descColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

                DataTemplate headerTemplate = new DataTemplate();
                FrameworkElementFactory headerFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
                headerTemplate.VisualTree = headerFactory;
                headerFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, e.PropertyName);

                DataTemplate textTemplate = new DataTemplate();
                FrameworkElementFactory textFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
                textTemplate.VisualTree = textFactory;
                textFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName) { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
                textFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);

                descColumn.Width = SetColumnWidth(25);

                descColumn.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate;
                descColumn.CellTemplate = textTemplate;
                Columns.Add(descColumn);
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
            }
        }
```

Как выровнять по центру заголовок? Как с ячейкой не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        Style cellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
        cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, Value = HorizontalAlignment.Center });
        e.Column.HeaderStyle = cellStyle;

        base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

XAML

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Название заголовка">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                   <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
private static DataGridColumnHeader GetHeader(DataGridColumn column, DependencyObject reference)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(reference); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(reference, i);

                var colHeader = child as DataGridColumnHeader;
                if ((colHeader != null) && (colHeader.Column == column))
                    return colHeader;

                colHeader = GetHeader(column, child);
                if (colHeader != null)
                    return colHeader;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Пример вызова

```
var columnHeader = GetHeader(DataGrid1.Columns[0], DataGrid1);
columnHeader.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Для C# нет примера?